# Magento 1.9 and nginx - ssl redirect loop

Tags: magento, ssl, nginx

I have a magento 1.9.2.4 installation on nginx server.When I enable SSL for frontend and for backend and now I have this error when I try to access any page in the site: The page isn't redirecting properly.

My db core_config_data is look like in the image:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to give a full steps , how to change Magento URL

**Check Current Status** :
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base%url%';

**Update URL** : 
update core_config_data set value = 'https://domainname/' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
update core_config_data set value = 'https://domainname/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';

**In WebServer** :
Please do not close 80 port untill you ensure that no http request is present 
another solution add 301 redirect

```
server {
      listen         80;
      server_name    XXXX.com;
      return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

**Clean Cache** :
Disable all cache

Flush Redis if you are using Redis or clean file cache